# Is there a reward for collecting Birdie Badges in Mario Golf GBC?

Tags: mario-golf-gbc

Whenever you score a birdie or better on a hole in Mario Golf for Game Boy Color you get a badge next to the hole on your scorecard. In Mario Golf for Nintendo 64 collecting Birdie Badges unlocked new characters. Does collecting Birdie Badges do anything in the Game Boy Color version?

[image]